# MySQL - Subquery Returns more than 1 row - subtraction issue

Tags: mysql, bitwise-operators

so I have 2 tables which are bookings and offices

Bookings:
[image: Bookings Table]

Offices:
[image: Office Table]

Please note that I am using BITWISE operations for the hours' availability which are in 30 min iterations.

Now the problem is that when a user needs to book a new booking I need to subtract the booked hours (sum(bookings.hours_booked)) from the office availability (offices.mon_hours) per office so that I can get a list of available offices.

This is my query so far, but this error is occurring: Subquery returns more than 1 row

```
select * from offices o  
where (mon_hrs -  (SELECT SUM(hours_booked)
 from bookings boo 
 where boo.week = 44
 AND boo.year = 2020
 AND CAST(from_timestamp as DATE) = '2020-10-26'
 GROUP BY office_id)) & 4 ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test

```
SELECT offices.* 
FROM offices   
JOIN (SELECT SUM(hours_booked) summ, office_id
      FROM bookings 
      WHERE week = 44
        AND year = 2020
-- next replacement avoids table scan and allows index usage
--      AND CAST(from_timestamp as DATE) = '2020-10-26'
        AND from_timestamp >= '2020-10-26' 
        AND from_timestamp < '2020-10-26' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
      GROUP BY office_id) sums ON offices.id = sums.office_id
WHERE (offices.mon_hrs - sums.summ) & 4 ;
```

Comment: OFFICE_ID  is an unknown colum i think using(office_ID), changed it to 'id' but still not working.
still unkown columns when change to id

Comment: @SigmondGatt Altered. PS. You'd provide your table structures as their CREATE TABLE, not as pictures.

Comment: can you edit 'ON office.id' to 'ON offices.id', thank you very much!

Comment: @SigmondGatt A typo. Edited.

Comment: sorry for disturbing again  :(, I found an issue with this query, as when there are other offices that can be available but not in the bookings table (there were no bookings to the table), will not appear in the results, i tried to do a left join to offices but nothing happened